# handbrake failing to encode an flv file

Tags: video-conversion, handbrake

using fast270p30 preset for mp4

activity log:

```
XPC: Service did report an error
[11:09:08] macgui: Error domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain
[11:09:08] macgui: Error code: 4097
[11:09:08] macgui: Error description: Couldn’t communicate with a helper application.
[11:09:08] macgui: Error debug description: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service on pid 901 named fr.handbrake.HandBrakeXPCService" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service on pid 901 named fr.handbrake.HandBrakeXPCService}
[11:09:08] macgui: Failed to create bookmark: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "Could not open() the item" UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Users/Macintosh/Library/Containers/fr.handbrake.HandBrake/Data/Movies/, NSDebugDescription=Could not open() the item}
[11:09:08] macgui: Queue Done, there are no more pending encodes
[11:09:08] macgui: Failed to create bookmark: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "Could not open() the item" UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Users/Macintosh/Library/Containers/fr.handbrake.HandBrake/Data/Movies/, NSDebugDescription=Could not open() the item}
XPC: Service did crash
[11:09:08] Compile-time hardening features are enabled
[11:09:08] hb_init: starting libhb thread
[11:09:08] macgui: QueueCore stopped preventing sleep
```

Comment: Having the same issue as well. I just upgraded via homebrew from a super old version. Went from 0.10.2 -> 1.3.0 @feca

Comment: Having this issue as well. I'm on 1.3.1. Did you find a solution? edit: also on osx, also encoding flv. my log stops on your first line, though.

Answer (score -1):

Nobody has stated what is inside their flv container. Is the video x264? VP6? Sorenson? Is the audio AAC, MP3, Nellymoser, Speex or ADPCM?

Please post specifics about the file you are trying to transcode.
MediaInfo is good for retrieving this kind of info.

Otherwise I am using HandBrake 1.5.1 win64 and haven't had issues with flv transcodes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1145259)

Comment: @rohit  How can I give a proper answer if they don't have a specific question? I have a problem with a video is not specific. I simply asked for more information. What is wrong with that? And why did you -1 me? Am I not allowed to ask for specifics?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, I don't do it without an explanation.  But someone else has and more people will.  Because asking for more info should be a comment.  it is not an answer.  Did you read that link

Comment: Well I'm actually pretty good at handbrake debugging and usage. I can't comment yet and I want to help. To help, I need more info. So how do you do that?

Comment: Just under the question is a **Add a Comment** link.  You need to be patient, until you have enough reputation.  We all had go through this.  :-)  But if you break the protocol then you will lose reputation.  Find something else you can answer.